# Change 50fps video into 25fps and keep the duration without reencoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing, matroska, framerate

I have a 50fps video, where every second frame is a duplicate of the previous frame. I want to upload this video to youtube and I want youtube to think it's a 25fps video. Is this possible?

For example changing some header or something. Searching for this I also encountered someone mentioning setting pts of every other frame to the same as the previous, but I don't know enough about this. Do you think this would work? and if so how would one go about automatically doing this?

Basically in an ideal scenario every second frame would be dropped from the video, but I understand that's not possible.

Close second I would add some tag to the file and player and youtube would interpret the video as 25fps and skip every second frame.

I want to do this without reencoding to keep the quality.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) say?

Comment: I tried -r 25 but with -c copy it has no effect, also in mkvtoolnix tried setting 25fps but it stretched the video to double the duration. I don't think there is any known way to do this, and I don't have enough knowledge to think of one.

Comment: You can reencode and keep the same quality with Handbrake.

Comment: What is the end goal of doing this? smaller file? or is there a different reason you want 25fps?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't believe you can. Unless I want a few tb size lossless video.

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess I just want it to be "correct" I don't want youtube to show 720p50 when it's not. Size wouldn't change much, I don't think.

Comment: You can remove every second frame in ffmpeg but not without reencoding, but you could use -q 0 to keep the same quality...